# ReactJS: Switch statement on state v.s explicit state declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This is more of a `design/engineering` question however it does pertain specifically to `React`. Are there any `pros` and/or `cons` when using these two types of `state designs`:

**Method 1.** I want to keep track of a selected category and a selected sub-category, so I set up `state` like this:

```
this.setState({
    selectedCategory: "Appliances", 
    selectedSubCategory: null
 })
```

**Method 2.** I want to keep track of a selected category/sub-category so I setup my state knowing I can use `switch` statements later to interpret the information:

```
this.setState({
   selection: "Appliances",
   type:"Category"
})
```

Of course the second way can manifest itself as many different types of setups (like an object, etc.). I just want to know if the most obvious way of storing `state` (Method 1) is sufficient in advanced use-cases. Does anyone even use Method 2?

Answer (score 1):

The state in React exists to control the render method of the `React.Component`. It is totally up to you how you will organize the state.
You may have your design, where React should not limit you at all.

> Switch statement on state v.s explicit state declarations

Well, you need to have some conditions.
Typically I would organize the simplest possible state structure and have some `if/else/switch` cases unless the state is what should be rendered.

> Okay, so you are saying that if the value of state directly relates to something being rendered then switch statements are just adding an unnecessary layer of complexity.

No, using conditions is a must.

Unless you should render the stat itself, or some `f(state)`, where `f` is a modification function.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that if the value of state directly relates to something being rendered then switch statements are just adding an unnecessary layer of complexity, where as they might also be a simpler form of state haha?. I think it is hard to be objective about design decisions hence why I asked, but thanks for giving me some insight.